# Love2d Should all inputs be in main.lua

Tags: lua, love2d

I am able to put inputs in modules, and it works fine, but am I not seeing a hidden downside to doing this? Should all inputs from the user be in main.lua?

Answer (score 2):

If by "inputs" you mean `love.keypressed`, `love.keyreleased` and other methods related to [user input](https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:Using_Input), then the answer is "no", they don't need to be in `main.lua` and there is no downside to putting them elsewhere as long as you load those modules/files from your script.